# Obtain all token transactions

Tags: transactions, tokens

I need to be able to retrieve all transactions that happened in a certain time period for arbitrary token on ethereum network. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: I thought about parsing data from all transactions sent to the address from etherscan, but that will not give transactions done via third-party smart contracts

Comment: `tokenContract.getPastEvents`